# How to find server control using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to find server control using jquery
e.g

```
$(".tab1").find("<%=lblTab1Heading.ClientID%>"); throws exception thrown & not caught
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed the `#` for IDs

```
              // here
$(".tab1").find("#<%=lblTab1Heading.ClientID%>");
```

If for some reason it is not working with the template parser, you can use the `$=` selector, like:

```
$(".tab1").find("[id$=lblTab1Heading]");
```

jQuery API

- [$= (ends with)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)
- [*= (contains)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: You don't need to use find, using `$("#<%=lblTab1Heading.ClientID%>")` will be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var MyControl = $("#<%=lblTab1Heading.ClientID%>");
```

Because it has an ID, you can simply select it on it's ID which is done with the hash:

`$('#ElementID')`

Comment: @Pekka he phrased it slightly wrongly, I'm assuming he means to say he wishes to access a server control rendered on the DOM with Jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need a # sign in your selector.  Try

```
$(".tab1").find("#<%=lblTab1Heading.ClientID%>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm too late for the answer but I guess this code will also help viewers finding it difficult to get the server control ID from JQuery

```
function GetClientID(id, context) {
   var el = $("#" + id, context);
   if (el.length < 1)
   el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
   return el;
}
```

and how you should call it

```
var clientId = GetClientID("serverControlId").attr("id");
var serverControl = document.getElementById(clientId);
```